# How do I remove a watch expression ( referring to variable not in current scope ) in Xcode IDE?

Tags: c++, xcode

I have pointer variable, `uint16_t *pointer` in function scope. When in the function, I added the watch expression: `*pointer >> 1` . This results in the debugger ( lldb ) crashing. I restart Xcode, and whenever I enter said function, thus the variable appears in the scope, it Xcode crashes again.
I would remove this watch expression, but when there no such variable in the current scope, the watch expression does not show up in the watch window.
The Xcode version is 7.3 , the code is C++